# Font in a gt table not working an in Rshiny app

Tags: r, shiny, html-table, fonts, gt

Font changes to a gt table are being reflected when we run the following code

```
    mtcars%>%
          head()%>%
          gt()%>%
          opt_table_font(
            font="Georgia"
  )
```

Table with fonts working properly
[image: Table1]

However, when the same thing is run using an R shiny app, then the font are not reflected correctly

```
library(shiny)
library(gt)

ui <- fluidPage(
  gt_output("table")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$table <- gt::render_gt({

    data<-mtcars%>%
      head()%>%
      gt()%>%
      opt_table_font(
        font="Georgia"
      
  )

  } 
  )

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not an expert on this but as far as I get it the issue is that the CSS rule for the font family set by `gt` is overwritten by the default shiny css. One option to get your "Georgia" font is by adding some custom css to set the font family for `gt` tables like so:

```
library(shiny)
library(gt)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .gt_table {
        font-family: 'Georgia'
      }
    "))
  ),
  
  gt_output("table")
)

server = function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$table <- gt::render_gt({
    data<-mtcars%>%
      head()%>%
      gt()
  } 
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: If we are driving the value of the font through a ui elements, then font value will be used as input$font within the server portion. Essentially we should be able to use a UI dropdown to provide font value and hence using a custom css element doesnt provide the required solution